# Is the use of "either" in the following context, good english and grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

> A: I don't like apple, what about you? Do you like it **either** ?
>
> B: No, I don't like it neighter. ( me neither )

Comment: Not only does this need more details, it's also essentially a [duplicate question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58206/question-about-the-use-of-either).

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the humidity. How about you?
-- I don't like it either.

I don't like the heat.
-- Me neither.

Here are a red hat and a blue hat. Do you like either (of them)?
--No, I like neither (of them).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it that those uses you mentioned are standard. But can we use the word "either" as I used to mean "I wonder if you are against me or not?" Do you like it either? Do you like it, although I do not like it?

Comment: @user5036 - That "extra" question you've put in this comment should be edited into your question. All you've done is ask "Is this correct?", and that's [not a good question on ELL](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: @user5036: No, the word *either* cannot be used in that way.  "Do you like it *even though* I do not like it?"