# Question about the use of "either"

Tags: grammar

Is the use of "either" in both conversations below, grammatically correct?

> - I don't like it.
> - I like it either. ( to mean: I like it, although you do not like it )

And

> - I don't like it, do you like it either?
> - Me neither.
> - Oh, that is great. We are very similar to each other!

Comment: Please don't put your question only in your title. Have a question in your question, not just [sentences to proofread](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/53d25f59-f706-4f1e-bd99-a2cbca1580d5/view-source). And it should be more than "is this correct?" Explain what you know about the word _either_, and tell us why you're not sure about these examples.

Answer (score 3):

***Statement A:***

> **Person A - I don't like it** (Person A doesn't like it)
>
> **Person B - *But* I like it** (Person B likes it and disagrees with person A)

seems more correct

***Statement B:***

> **Person A - I don't like it** (Person A doesn't like it)
>
> **Person B - Me neither** (Person B agrees with person A and doesn't like it)

Or another scenario

> **Person A - I don't like it, do you like it?** (Person A doesn't like it, and asks person B if he likes it)
>
> **Person B - No, I don't like it (either).** (Person B replies that he does not like it as well)

*In this case, you can use the word either because you are answering the question, and you agree with Person A*. The word 'either' is also only really used to choose between 2 items. E.g. "Do you like either of them?", and thus cannot be used to pose a question.

For scenario B, if you are agreeing with the person who doesn't like it, "me neither" is the correct form.

If you want to ask someone if they like it as well, you cannot say "do you like it either", but you have to say simply, "do you like it?"